# Typescript recursive subset of type

Tags: typescript

Is it possible in Typescript to create subset of type similar to this?

```
type Schema = {
  user: {
    name: string;
    age: number;
    profile: {
      isCool?: boolean;
    };
  };
};

const wantedSubset = {
  user: {
    name: true,
    profile: {
      isCool: true
    }
  }
};

type ExpectedType = {
  user: {
    name: string;
    profile: {
      isCool?: boolean;
    };
  };
};

const result: ExpectedType = desiredCode(wantedSubset);
```

In case it's not clear I want to have `desiredCode` function that given object `wantedSubset` will return anything but typed as recursive use of `declare function pick<T, K extends keyof T>(obj: T, ...keys: K[]): Pick<T, K>;`

I would like to apply this `Pick` recursively on `Schema` but I don't know how I can recursively "refer" to `Schema` type.

I tried something like this:

```
function gql<Q, S, QK extends keyof Q, SK extends keyof S, K extends SK & QK>(
  query: Q | true,
  schema: S
) {
  if (query === true) return (query as unknown) as S;
  const keys = Object.keys(query) as K[];
  const result = {} as Pick<S, K>;
  keys.forEach(k => {
    result[k] = gql(query[k], schema[k]);
  });

  return result;
}

const result = gql(wantedSubset, wantedSubset as unknown as Schema)
```

but it doesn't work the way I would like it to. It simply return result of Pick instead of applying it recursively.

Basically the problem is how to build object dynamically so typescript will be able to infer return value.

https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=type%20Schema%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20user%3A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20name%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20age%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20profile%3A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20isCool%3F%3A%20boolean%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%7D%2C%0D%0A%20%20foo%3A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20bar%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20wantedSubset%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20user%3A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20name%3A%20true%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20profile%3A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20isCool%3A%20true%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20gql%3CQ%2C%20S%2C%20QK%20extends%20keyof%20Q%2C%20SK%20extends%20keyof%20S%2C%20K%20extends%20SK%20%26%20QK%3E(%0D%0A%20%20query%3A%20Q%20%7C%20true%2C%0D%0A%20%20schema%3A%20S%0D%0A)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20if%20(query%20%3D%3D%3D%20true)%20return%20(query%20as%20unknown)%20as%20S%3B%0D%0A%20%20const%20keys%20%3D%20Object.keys(query)%20as%20K%5B%5D%3B%0D%0A%20%20const%20result%20%3D%20%7B%7D%20as%20Pick%3CS%2C%20K%3E%3B%0D%0A%20%20keys.forEach(k%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20result%5Bk%5D%20%3D%20gql(query%5Bk%5D%2C%20schema%5Bk%5D)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%7D)%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20return%20result%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20result%20%3D%20gql(wantedSubset%2C%20wantedSubset%20as%20unknown%20as%20Schema)%0D%0A%0D%0Aresult.user.age%20%2F%2F%20should%20be%20an%20error!%0D%0Aresult.user.name%20%2F%2F%20works%20OK%0D%0Aresult.user.profile.isCool%20%2F%2F%20works%20OK%0D%0Aresult.foo%20%2F%2F%20works%20like%20expected

Comment: You really want `ExpectedType['user']['profile']['isCool']` to be `true | undefined` and not `boolean | undefined` ?

Comment: @jcalz Thanks for spotting this mistake - I want `boolean | undefined` - fixed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I think you want `wantedSubset` to conform to a type where each property is either `true` or itself an object of that type.  We need to do a bit of footwork to get TypeScript to infer such a type where the value `true` is treated as type `true` and not `boolean` (at least until TS3.4 comes out and gives us [`const` contexts](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/29510)):

```
type WantedSubset = { [k: string]: true | WantedSubset };
const asWantedSubset = <RP extends WantedSubset>(wantedSubset: RP) => wantedSubset;

const wantedSubset = asWantedSubset({
  user: {
    name: true,
    profile: {
      isCool: true
    }
  }
}); // no error, so that type works.
```

Now comes the type `RecursivePick` and friends.  First of all, given a type `T`, you want a `WantedSubset` type that conforms to it.  I'll call that a `RecusivePicker<T>`:

```
type RecursivePicker<T> = { 
  [K in keyof T]?: T[K] extends object | undefined ? RecursivePicker<T[K]> : true 
}
```

So if `T` is `Schema`, then `RecursivePicker<Schema>` gives you:

```
type RPSchema = RecursivePicker<Schema>
// type RPSchema = {
//  user?: {
//    age?: true;
//    name?: true;
//    profile?: {
//      isCool?: true;
//    }
//  }
// }
```

That can be a constraint on the type of `wantedSubset` that you'll allow to pick from `Schema` types.

And here is `RecursivePick` in all its recursive mapped conditional <strike>horror</strike> glory:

```
type RecursivePick<T, KO extends RecursivePicker<T>> =
  Pick<{ [K in keyof T]: K extends keyof KO ?
    KO[K] extends true ? T[K] :
    KO[K] extends infer KOK ?
    KOK extends RecursivePicker<T[K]> ? RecursivePick<T[K], KOK> :
    never : never : never }, keyof T & keyof KO>;
```

It basically walks down through properties of `T` and examines the corresponding property of `KO`.  If the property is `true` it returns the property of `T` unchanged.  If the property is itself a bag of properties it recurses down.  And if the property isn't there, it returns `never`.  And that whole thing is `Pick`ed so that only keys appearing in both `T` and `KO` appear in the final output (this is a bit of fiddling to make sure that all the relevant [mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types) are homomorphic, meaning that optional properties stay optional).

Let's verify it works:

```
type ExpectedType = RecursivePick<Schema, typeof wantedSubset>;
```

You can walk through that, but let's make the compiler verify it:

```
type ExpectedTypeManual = {
  user: {
    name: string;
    profile: {
      isCool?: boolean;
    };
  };
};

type MutuallyExtends<T extends U, U extends V, V=T> = true

// if no error in the next line, then ExpectedType and ExpectedTypeManual are 
//  structurally the same
type NoErrorHere = MutuallyExtends<ExpectedType, ExpectedTypeManual>
```

So that all works.  Your function would be typed something like this:

```
declare function gql<Q extends RecursivePicker<S>, S>(
  query: Q | true,
  schema: S
): RecursivePick<S, Q>;

const result = gql(wantedSubset, null! as Schema); // looks good
```

Getting the implementation of the function to compile with no error might require an [overload](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#overloads) as conditional types are notoriously difficult to infer:

```
function gql<Q extends RecursivePicker<S>, S>(
  query: Q | true,
  schema: S
): RecursivePick<S, Q>;
function gql(query: any, schema: object): object {
  return {}; // something better here
}
```

All right, hope that helps; good luck!

Comment: Would it be possible to detect in `asWantedSubset` that it's not a subset? (That some property doesn't exists in schema)

Comment: `type ExactRecursivePicker<T, RP>  = {[K in keyof RP]: K extends keyof T ? T[K] extends object ? ExactRecursivePicker<T[K], RP[K]> : true : never}; const asWantedSubset = <RP extends ExactRecursivePicker<Schema, RP>>(wantedSubset: RP) => wantedSubset;`

Comment: That would have been caught in `gql()`, but if you want it caught earlier you can do something like the above.

Comment: There's just one last issue - when I make `profile` optional (`profile?:`) then the information is lost when I type `result.user.profile.isCool` - typescript says that it's fine, but should mention that profile is possibly undefined. Do you know how to remediate this?

Comment: Possibly you can fix it by changing `RecursivePicker` to  `type RecursivePicker<T> = { [K in keyof T]?: T[K] extends object | undefined ? RecursivePicker<T[K]> : true }`, but I'm not 100% sure.