# Create a new subset object from array of keys with the correct type infer

Tags: typescript

Given an object and a string array of keys (these keys will exist in the object), construct a new object containing those keys and its corresponding value **with the correct Typescript typing**. That is:

```js
/**
 * This function will construct a new object
 * which is the subset values associated to 
 * the keys array
**/
function extractFromObj<T>(obj: T, keys: (keyof T)[])

// in here, suppose `post` is a huge object,
// but the intellicence should only show keys
// from the keys array
const { id, properties, created_time } = extractFromObj(post, ['id', 'properties', 'created_time'])
```

## My solution (wrong so far)

```js
function extractFromObj<T>(obj: T, keys: (keyof T)[]): Record<keyof typeof keys, any> {
  return keys.reduce((newObj, curr) => {
    newObj[curr] = obj[curr]

    return newObj
  }, {} as Record<keyof typeof keys, any>)
}

const {} = extractFromObj(post, ['id', 'properties', 'created_time']) // wrong
```

Assistance needed please & thank you

## Update

I forgot to mention, the solution should also work for when a key is nested inside the object. For example:

```js
const obj = {
  "object": "page",
  "id": "b03f9945-528a-4a1c-a280-6972bbc49462",
  "created_time": "2021-11-07T11:24:00.000Z",
  "last_edited_time": "2021-11-07T11:24:00.000Z",
  "cover": null,
  "foo": {
    "bar": {
      "baz": {
        "properties": "hello world"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I know that this is an overengineering a bit, but you might be interested in this solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67242871/declare-a-type-that-allows-all-parts-of-all-levels-of-another-type#answer-67247652 and https://catchts.com/deep-pick

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure I'd recommend this solution, but since you want , here you have:

```js
type KeysUnion<T, Cache extends string = ''> =
    Record<string, unknown> extends T ? string :
    T extends PropertyKey ? Cache : {
        [P in keyof T]:
        P extends string
        ? Cache extends ''
        ? KeysUnion<T[P], `${P}`>
        : Cache | KeysUnion<T[P], `${P}`>
        : never
    }[keyof T]

const isObject = (obj: unknown): obj is Record<string, unknown> =>
    typeof obj === 'object' && obj !== null && !Array.isArray(obj)

type Primitives = string | number | boolean | symbol | null | undefined | bigint

// credits goes to https://stackoverflow.com/a/50375286
type UnionToIntersection<U> = (U extends any ? (k: U) => void : never) extends (
    k: infer I
) => void
    ? I
    : never;

type ExtractFromObj<
    Obj,
    Keys,
    Result = {}
    > =
    (Keys extends string[]
        ? (Obj extends Primitives
            ? Result
            : {
                [Prop in keyof Obj]:
                (Prop extends Keys[number]
                    ? Result & Pick<Obj, Prop>
                    : (Obj[Prop] extends Primitives
                        ? Result
                        :ExtractFromObj<Obj[Prop], Keys, Result>)
                )
            }[keyof Obj])
        : never)

function extractFromObj<
    Obj extends Record<string, unknown>,
    Keys extends KeysUnion<Obj>,
    InferedKeys extends Keys[]
>(
    obj: Obj,
    keys: [...InferedKeys],
    result?: UnionToIntersection<ExtractFromObj<Obj, [...InferedKeys]>>
): UnionToIntersection<ExtractFromObj<Obj, [...InferedKeys]>>

function extractFromObj(
    obj: Record<string, unknown>,
    keys: string[],
    result: Partial<Record<string, unknown>> = {}
) {
    if (Object.keys(obj).length === 0) {
        return result
    }
    return Object.keys(obj).reduce((acc, prop) => {
        if (keys.includes(prop)) {
            return {
                ...acc,
                [prop]: obj[prop]
            }

        }
        const reduced = obj[prop];

        if (isObject(reduced)) {
            return extractFromObj(reduced, keys, { ...acc, ...result })
        }
        return acc

    }, result)
}


const foo = extractFromObj({
    'id':'hello',
    "foo": {
        "bar": {
            "baz": {
                "properties": "hello world"
            }
        }
    }
}, ['id','baz']) // ok

foo.id // string
foo.baz // { "properties": "hello world" }

const foo2 = extractFromObj({
    "object": "page",
    "id": "b03f9945-528a-4a1c-a280-6972bbc49462",
    "created_time": "2021-11-07T11:24:00.000Z",
    "last_edited_time": "2021-11-07T11:24:00.000Z",
    "cover": null,
    "foo": {
        "bar": {
            "baz": {
                "properties": "hello world"
            }
        }
    }
}, ['id', 'bazzz']) // expected error
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-DAfc0gybIALyCiWK+Xx-EIhp5kQBINS1dgcOYliqiomDSR8NAyF0bAQJ8di0TknS7y+AC2P8HIRNKEi5QVcN+N01xbCgmCrOshj3w4cgfz-AD1NeQywB6MSEEIOyaJEUVZLkkLrJOM4Ll48L6LXdMQqkTIdC-JZCM-NyMH-V4gNvAityhJQVDUexNCgAEkRMCDXFQgq2hbToAJEarZE7Q9A0YWr0K8NpsKkEQd1vcEohA3cFiiBJuSmtrDmdNoemaQNqOAaxZw6FA207bte1SzpnIy38so8jTJumg9Zs6hYchENFQWbdbNq7Q4dvlPaP1cw7ssAk6pu5GaOvmm6xWSlBdpNMwDvc15BtcYbCphErygRQFkRamQzgTMoHGwtGoCWmCom8EhAjQEh6WwBQithUruGRyqbs+eCTxiZo0GyfTXnebkMeFF5gW5Q0eGAChcQEYt5yYljA2ALR2BNfGaOORaIBluWoAArmefBfmOq0MgIC+L5yDIQgwHY08xEl+i2e+DHeVB+ktHtBAvjN-xgQlhy8ZV2WTStxyoF+43ceshI3Z8sEvPDmSIrFFiENCm47l1-WXQEcEw-YnJn0kCiba+PkNa-L4U+dD2WdC1xpd99KPqhl4S+dPXnUIDHCGiQOpuDzvuQVj5hkS0KE6ln21eNuPZGGQg+5ChOxSTj5Mn1T4Ibro7of9oQV0ERxBCoRkMEEXGACIl4wY-GIo4+nmJi+K+s6+SAALzvzeH-Dw55XDO-j-3rMoEMMoekjBj5e2HvRcBMgE5TygAkQQ298CCBvk-QQOR5y+gpLoYG+peQugwZhJKODkFQAwR3Y+H8SbfyiL-CAB8AFAJAVAOekgF5QDPlWFe70vyfQAl8Tex9CRfh-mAEg3AIDHxPiuH+TwyyZAAJxyIACyFgALTVhrCQFRiiSAAEYyAqJILWYsKi6xyPLFWJ4TwyCKKUXWKsEjmjHwDEaegjAAD68ppTiOoVWYsVYdEqJ0QE4s5ZcBBMcFWRRjhizFm5DE4sAAtBxt5j70hIGwNxQZXEeJlN4qAx9fH+MCcE0J4TInRNifEpJJ8lDpjvtaekJ8z6vyvjfdgLTK6yEfi-S+nTCjkPYp-NAVD8l-yjIA9gwDQF9KYRRSBszJAwLgQgoQyCn4oLQSQv0tBIBfmdKODkyggA)

`extractFromObj` - iterates recursively through each object property and check wheter it exists in `keys` or not. If exists - merge it with `result`.

`KeysUnion` - is described thoroughly in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69667244/type-for-a-dot-separated-path-to-type/69881190#69881190) answer. See also related links

> Also, IntelliSense doesn't seem to work when trying to restructure

I just thought you will not ask

Here is the code which is responsible for iteratinng through `Obj` keys recursively and obtaining appropriate value.

```js
type ExtractFromObj<
    Obj,
    Keys,
    Result = {}
    > =
    (Keys extends string[]
        ? (Obj extends Primitives
            ? Result
            : {
                [Prop in keyof Obj]:
                (Prop extends Keys[number]
                    ? Result & Pick<Obj, Prop>
                    : (Obj[Prop] extends Primitives
                        ? Result
                        :ExtractFromObj<Obj[Prop], Keys, Result>)
                )
            }[keyof Obj])
        : never)
```

**`Reducer`** - does basically the same as `extractFromObj` function - but in type scope.
[image]

Generic arguments `Obj`, `Keys`, `Result` represents `function extractFromObj` arguments and have same semantic meaning.

If `Keys` is empty tuple (`Keys extends string[]`), **just like** `Object.keys(obj).length === 0`  - we need ti return `Result`.

`[Prop in keyof Obj]:` - iterates through `Obj` keys, **just like** `Object.keys(obj).reduce`.

`Prop extends Keys[number]` - checks whether iterated property `Prop` exists in the union of all `Keys`. **Just like** `keys.includes(prop)`.

If `Prop` existsm in the `Keys` return merged accumulator with approapriate key/value pair: `Result & Pick<Obj, Prop>` **just like**

```js
return {
          ...acc,
          [prop]: obj[prop]
       }
```

If `Prop` does not exists in `Keys` and `Obj[Prop]` is an object, call recursively

```js
(Obj[Prop] extends Primitives ? Result:ExtractFromObj<Obj[Prop], Keys, Result>)
```

**just like**

```js
 if (isObject(reduced)) {
            return extractFromObj(reduced, keys, { ...acc, ...result })
        }
```

`[keyof Obj]` - at the end, gathers all object values in a union and `UnionToIntersection` merges it.

That's it.

Comment: Thank you, Capn'! It's quite a lot to take in. Let me try to understand it 

Comment: @Humbledore made small update, added link to better understand how KeysUnion works

Comment: When I try to use it in my codebase, I am getting "Type instantiation is excessively deep and possibly infinite". Any idea why arent we getting this in the playground?

Comment: Also, IntelliSense doesn't seem to work when trying to restructure:

```
const { id, baz } = extractFromObj({
  "object": "page",
  "id": "b03f9945-528a-4a1c-a280-6972bbc49462",
  "created_time": "2021-11-07T11:24:00.000Z",
  "last_edited_time": "2021-11-07T11:24:00.000Z",
  "cover": null,
  "foo": {
    "bar": {
      "baz": {
        "properties": "hello world"
      }
    }
  }
}, ['id', 'baz'])
```

Comment: According to `Type instantiation is excessively deep and possibly` - please use most recent version of my example. I made an update some time ago

Comment: @Humbledore made an update

Comment: Lol, you're an absolute star!  Never thought it would be as complicated as this. Kudos to you 

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239006/discussion-between-captain-yossarian-and-humbledore).

Answer (score 5):

It looks like you are looking for the [Pick<Type, Keys>](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#picktype-keys) utility type.

You may implement your function as follows:

```ts
const post = {
  id: 1,
  properties: 2,
  created_time: 'aaa',
  other_prop: 2
}

function extractFromObj<T, K extends keyof T>(obj: T, keys: K[]): Pick<T, K> {
  return keys.reduce((newObj, curr) => {
    newObj[curr] = obj[curr]

    return newObj
  }, {} as Pick<T, K>)
}

const result1 = extractFromObj(post, ['id', 'properties', 'created_time'])
```

On top of that:

- you may prefer to use vargargs over an array for keys
- if you target ES2019, you can use `Object.fromEntries`

```ts
const post = {
  id: 1,
  properties: 2,
  created_time: 'aaa',
  other_prop: 2
}

function extractFromObjEs2019<T, K extends keyof T>(obj: T, ...keys: K[]): Pick<T, K> {
  const entries = keys.map(key => ([key, obj[key]]));
  return Object.fromEntries(entries);
}

const result2 = extractFromObjEs2019(post, 'id', 'properties', 'created_time')
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=6#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)

**Update:**

For recursive version, you may start with [this playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=6#code/C4TwDgpgBA6ghgO2BAJgZQK4CMDOFhQC8UA3lANoDWAXFDsAE4CWCA5gLq2MbQA%20siZOmx4CAXwDcAKCkBjAPYJ6UeVgBWRUlKhQARKrURZwXbV1g4rCLoA02vUxSm9WAAwBmAGYBObwBYAVgBaAIAmAA44IL84AEZZILgI1yCANm8AdlCsLFk-f1TQ23tdWQYIOCEAfWAmAFtrM1DXUNig2LbXDIAVDupQv2pXVwA6YdcALWKdXQAbOHoq1CZq2obnXWbW9s6evoGh0fGpuxmFADcIBmcEDFnZ071PeXlnEnsZrDhr2nedf5ccAAXm8PgC9GAGPJIAxahAcBsABYQe7yKAAd3kDFmTke4IhUJhcJwRTMyNRGKxON0YJ0YjB9LpUnpUlAkCgACUjBgGDgmJcAApMWSUK4AHm6AD5NGR7OQANJQFhQUUgeSeKDddgAflo3QV7CgEAAHsgECgcCp1EYCPwMOaIJ4WKgoNrOdzefyIEKReL9fL2NKuAweFBmTI2dAOQKAPLqTRc2Q8vmC4WihhiyPqq1qSUR8BRj0p71piU2KDymNG00Qc2WxPJr0%209MSyXSwj2ZtisgKpUIFUQNUarW0RUms0WgdDitV7VgysG6sTy3caBu-2G6jzmOL8e1ycsTxXGeKucAytjmt191Jz2p30ZjfSt0Nu8lkUSg3li9BsEICCXAwUC0P%20gHAVAoHHmI5aqtm3RQAAZFO2aVpK0hyIoyjooIqCYLg%20AyvYjjBjwjxlBUqz1BAJEQI8zzyL8YJfAwjH4l8QKsfiUCQtCVzEjRtJQIy-zQfY9JiFACxQAoSjAOhnj2sYTCKFArAAI6zGKACKS77vWRZNmm4poJK5YmQAFPYak8AwIC0Fpjw4LIyJ1HAtBoFIACUtCvsWXZoOWWnSn8UDlMAPL9nGhjGCMtaMEw8LmdZVwgJ5IzlCgGCyBA5nmf%206JReWVDluc7CeUQwVgkwGrmecRCEMQq7lSFAL5VFVCGsQTkuXAHVhgCEkongWj4m16h9cQ6mzLV5bdRArkdZ5DJgmFEUQRABXqGJ5YkBJUm%20YZH4BVAQVLSyGGyaF8J3AQk0aeZ2FILhIj4OWBiedIMk4PIswQCMszyKw5nlDgN0fTIUhAA),
based on [Typescript recursive subset of type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54949052/typescript-recursive-subset-of-type)

Comment: Despite the fact that both: your solution and OP's are O(n), I think solution with `reduce` will be more efficient. https://tsplay.dev/w6X2ym

Comment: @captain-yossarian I agree, It's an extra - albeit not massive - overhead IMHO.

Comment: Thank you for your solution. It works like a charm. However, I forgot to mention (I will update my question), how does it work if the key is nested in the object? Can your solution be changed to recursively go inside the nested object to find the first occurrence of the key?

Comment: A good point to start the updated version": https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54949052/typescript-recursive-subset-of-type

Answer (score 0):

This is a modern slightly changed version of how [Ramda](https://github.com/ramda/ramda) does the pick.

```
function pick<T, K extends string>(obj: T, names: readonly K[]) {
  const result: unknown = {};
  for (let name of names) {
    if (name in obj) {
      result[name] = obj[name as unknown as keyof T];
    }
  }
  return result as Pick<T, Exclude<keyof T, Exclude<keyof T, K>>>;
}
```